# Transfering the form data to more than one page using php

Tags: php

I have created one textfield and one dropdownlist and a button in my "index.php" page as follows:

```
    <form value="indexform" action="" method="post">
    <b>Number:</b><input type="text" name="number"/><br/>
    <b>Network:</b>
    <select name="network">
    <option selected="">please...</option>
    <option value="1">Bsnl</option>
    <option value="2">Idea</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="proceed" value="submit">
    </form>
```

and i have used the php code as follows for the above form:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['network']) && isset($_POST['number']))
    {
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $network = $_POST['network'];
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['network']))
    {
    switch($network)
    {
    case "1":header("Location:Bsnl.php");break;
    case "2":header("Location:Idea.php");break;
    default:exit();
    }
    ?>
```

and i have crated two pages "Bsnl.php" and "Idea.php" Based on the selection taken in the dropdownlist the page will be redirected into either Bsnl/Idea.php

I have created the Bsnl/Idea.php page containg one textfield and submit button the code is as follows:

```
    <form value="Bsnlform action="default.php" method="post">
    <b>Amount:</b><input type="text" name="amount"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

php code is as follows:

```
    <?php
    if(!empty($_POST['amount']))
    {
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    }
    ?>
```

atlast i want to print the entire form details(indexform as well as Bsnl/idea form) on the default.php page can any one help me how to do to print the values on default.php upto now i have tried the php code as follows:

```
    <?php
    echo $amount;
    echo $network;
    echo $number;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to enable session_start();
and change to this like so....

```
    <?php
    //Enable session first
    session_start();

    //Flush any existing session variables, you can choose where/if you wanna do this
    session_unset();     

    if(isset($_POST['network']) && isset($_POST['number']))
    {
    $_SESSION['number'] = $_POST['number'];
    $_SESSION['network'] = $_POST['network'];
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['network']))
    {
    switch($_SESSION['network'])
    {
    case "1":header("Location:Bsnl.php");break;
    case "2":header("Location:Idea.php");break;
    default:exit();
    }
    ?>
```

Then change this to this....

```
<?php
//Session enable again
session_start();

if(!empty($_POST['amount']))
{
$_SESSION['amount'] = $_POST['amount'];
}
?>
```

Then in your next file....

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['amount'];
echo $_SESSION['network'];
echo $_SESSION['number'];
?>
```

Of course on your other page you wont echo $_SESSION['amount'], because it wont be set yet...

Comment: not working for the above given code!!!   because in index.php page the form containg action attribute is filled with bsnl.php any changes i want to do

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean??  as you have it now the first form really goes nowhere, I assumed that was just a typo on your part, but you have action=""...anyway.....whats the problem?

Comment: the data which i have entered into the fields was not transferring into third page

Comment: Ok in my example above, I have 3 blocks, Im assuming the second block in the middle is the 'processor' for after you hit submit on either Bsn1.php and Idea.php?  No?  It should be working unless you weren't clear on your files....